# Extract content with Entity Recognition on existing metadata in GSA

Tags: regex, search, google-search-appliance

When using entity recognition in GSA does it only work on "content" of a site/document or does it also work to extracting certain parts of existing metadata?

I have a metadata that i wish to only extract a specific part of the metadata content field matching a regex. Is this possibly with GSA Entity recognition? Or maybe a different tool inside the Google Search Appliance.

Answer (score 1):

Entity recognition is only able to extract entities from document contents and URLs.

To clean up metadata you have a few options:

- do it in the source repo
- use a doc filter or transform if it's being fed by a connector
- use a metadata and url feed to add new (sanitized) metadata

Comment: I am trying to clean up some bad metadata. E.g.
metadata content `Subject;Cars`. The issues is that i only want to extract "Cars". But it seems that entity recognition doesn't allow this.